# why won't my sorting algorithm work?

Tags: java

code should do this: a) Given an unsorted array of integers, your task is to sort the array by applying the following algorithm
(Assume that the input doesn’t contain duplicates ):
Execute the following steps starting from the first element in the array:
– Count the number of smaller elements to find the correct position i.
– If the element is in its correct position, move to the succeeding element.
– Otherwise, swap the current element with the one found in position i.
– Repeat the previous steps till you reach the last element.

Example:
5 7 3 6 9
check a[0], there is one element smaller that it, so it shoould be swapped with the element at
position1.
7 5 3 6 9
check the new element a[0]. it should move to position 3.
6 5 3 7 9
check the new element a[0]. it should move to position 2.
3 5 6 7 9
check the new element a[0]. it is in its correct position, so we move to the succeeding element a[1].

```
public class  Assignment1_T11_25_2729_Sara_Aly {
private int[] a;
private int max;
private int n;
int position=0;
public  Assignment1_T11_25_2729_Sara_Aly (int max){
    a= new int[max];
}
public void insert(int x){
    a[n]=x;
    n++;
        }
public void sort(){
    int out=0, smaller=0;
    while(out<n){
        for(int in=out+1;in<n;n++){
            if(a[in]<a[out])
                smaller++;
        }
        if (smaller==0){
            out++;
        }
        else {
            swap(a[out], a[smaller]);
        }
    }
    }
private void swap (int one, int two){
    int temp=a[one];
    a[one]=a[two];
    a[two]=temp;
}
    public void display(){
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.print(a[i]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
public static void main(String[]args){
    int maxsize=5;
    Assignment1_T11_25_2729_Sara_Aly trial;
    trial= new  Assignment1_T11_25_2729_Sara_Aly(maxsize);
    trial.insert(5);
    trial.insert(7);
    trial.insert(3);
    trial.insert(6);
    trial.insert(9);
    trial.display();
    trial.sort();
    trial.display();
}
}

    Tried a few algorithims to get it to work but for some reason it won't sort any suggestions??
```

also tried this the sorting method but no luck.

```
public void sort(){
boolean finished = false;
int position =0;
    while (position<max){
        if (finished==true){
        position++;
        finished =false;
        }
        else {
            int smaller=0;
            for (int j = position+1; j<max; j++){
            int temp=a[position];
                if (a[j] <a[position]){
                    smaller++;
                }
            }
            if (smaller==0){
                finished= true;
            }
            else {
                int temp= a[smaller];
                a[smaller]=a[position];
                a[position]=temp;
                }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please don't use the [homework] tag anymore: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147100/195634

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you have not described exactly what the problem is, I would assume that, in your `first code`, the `for-loop` inside the `while` loop of your `sort` method is giving you a problem: -

```
    for(int in = out+1; in < n; n++) {
        if(a[in] < a[out])
            smaller++;
    }
```

Here, you are incrementing `n++` rather than `in++`. Check onto that. Change it to `in++`. You might be getting into infinite loop because of that.

Also, there is a problem in your `swap` method. You have invoked your `swap` method with actual array element, but you are considering them as `indices` in the method.

```
swap(a[out], a[smaller]);  // Called with element `a[out]`

private void swap (int one, int two) {

    int temp=a[one];    // This is equivalent to a[a[out]]
    a[one]=a[two];
    a[two]=temp;
}
```

You can just pass index to your method: -

So, invoke your swap method like : - `swap(out, smaller);`

**UPDATE**: -In your `while` loop of `sort` method, add `smaller = 0;` as the first statement. To re-initialize it to 0.

Comment: the problem is that when I run the algorithim it doesn't put the array in order but gives me back the same array, Although i think the sway algorithim is correct

Comment: @SaraAlaaKhodeir.. Did you read my post? I have clearly explained that your `swap` algorithm is not doing what you think.

Comment: @SaraAlaaKhodeir Change your for-loop and the way you invoke your swap method, and its all done. I think those are the only problem in your code.

Comment: I did change them but it gives the same thing

Comment: public void sort(){
  int out=0, smaller=0;

  while(out<max){
   for(int in=out+1;in<max;in++){
    if(a[in]<a[out])
     smaller++;
   }
   if (smaller==0){
    out++;
   }
   else {
    swap(out,smaller);
   }
   smaller=0;
  }

  }

 private void swap (int one, int two){
  int temp=a[one];
  a[one]=a[two];
  a[two]=temp;
 }

Comment: @SaraAlaaKhodeir. Ok, one more problem is you have not re-initialized your `smaller` to 0 inside `while` loop.. Add `smaller = 0` as the first statement in your while loop in sort method. Apart from the change I told..

Comment: @SaraAlaaKhodeir. Well, you have added it in the code you just posted here. Did it work?

Comment: @SaraAlaaKhodeir. This code, which you just posted in your comment will work fine.

Comment: so could there be a problem with jcreator because it still returns the same array

Comment: @SaraAlaaKhodeir. No no. Your code is working fine, when I tried.. Did you try running with all the changes, and `adding smaller = 0; as the first statement in your while loop`?

Comment: yeah i did same output : 5 7 3 6 9 
5 7 3 6 9 

Process completed.

Comment: public void sort(){
  int out=0, smaller=0;

  while(out<max){
   for(int in=out+1;in<max;in++){
    if(a[in]<a[out])
     smaller++;
   }
   if (smaller==0){
    out++;
   }
   else {
    swap(out,smaller);
   }
   smaller=0;
  }

  }

Comment: @SaraAlaaKhodeir. Ah I'm sorry, actually I removed the line from my post that said : - `replace your `n` with `max`. Actually you don't need that. Let it be `n`. Really sorry for that. :( Let it be `n`.

Comment: @SaraAlaaKhodeir. Great :) . Now you can mark my answer accepted. By clicking the arrow besides the answer. :)